# css overflow: scroll. start from the bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a chat widget, which is minimized (collapsed and fixed to bottom of page) by default and then maximized when clicked.

It has a fixed height, and `overflow-y: scroll`. I want the scrollbar to start at the bottom and scroll upwards, but this is prettry problematic.

If I never collapse the widget, which I do with `widget.toggle('blind')` (JQuery), I can simply scroll with javascript on page load: using `.scrollTop()`, however, I want the widget to initially be collapsed. Using `.scrollTop()` on the collapsed widget has no effect! Furthermore, whenever I collapse/expand the widget, it scrolls all the way to the top.

Is there a library or do you have some hints to solve this?

Comment: This seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426780/javascript-jquery-keep-a-div-scrolled-to-the-bottom-while-resizing-the-page-ve

Comment: indeed.. this is exactly it. But it doesn't work, when the widget is collapsed (overflowing box is hidden, i.e. height=0). So I'm looking for an alternative or something I've overlooked

Comment: Could you tie a JS event into collapsing/expanding the widget so it can scroll to bottom?

Comment: yea @PaulRedmond, I attached it as a callback `widget.toggle('blind', function(){/* scroll here */})`. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

1. Declare your chatView (widget) minimized height (**5vh** in my example) by default
2. When user wants to open the chatView (click in my example), you adding class (**open** in my example) and increase it's height (**90vh** in my example). With transition property - you get wanted animation.
3. Use mentioned jQuery method .scrollTop with needed container height (**#chatView>div** in my example), which insures it scroll to the bottom.

```js
$(function(){
 $("#chatView").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("open").scrollTop($("#chatView>div").height());
        });
});
```

```css
  *{
   margin:0;
  }
  footer{
   height:10vh;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
  }
  #chatView{
   width: 20vw;
   background:red;
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   height:4vh;
   transition: height 1s;
   overflow-y:scroll;
  }
  #chatView.open{
   height: 90vh;
  }
  #chatView>div{
   background:green;
   height: 95vh;
  }
  #chatView>figure{
   height: 4vh;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer>
  <div id="chatView" >
    <figure></figure>
    <div ></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```