# how to make content aligned from the end while able to scroll in a fixed parent

Tags: html, css

Here is the thing: I want to display some content which can be scrolled in a fixed component. Then I wanna the content to start form bottom, so I set content's class to {position: absolute;bottom:0;}, but the result is that the content can't be scrolled any more.Is there a solution to this problem?

```
---parent(position fixed)
----contents
-------empty space
-------empty space
-------text
----contents end

after add a text:
---parent(position fixed)
----contents
-------empty space
-------text2
-------text
----contents end

after add more text
---parent(position fixed)
----contents        -
(-------text4(5..and so on)(scroll to see))
-------text3        |
-------text2        able to scroll
-------text         |
----contents end    -
```

`

```css
.shade {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="shade">
  <div class="content">
    <div> 1 </div>
    <div> 2 </div>
    <div> 3 </div>
    <div> 4 </div>
    <div> 5 </div>
    <div> 6 </div>
    <div> 7 </div>
    <div> 8 </div>
    <div> 9 </div>
    <div> 10 </div>
    <div> 11 </div>
    <div> 12 </div>
    <div> 13 </div>
    <div> 14 </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position:absolute` always take the element to absolut position. This means the parent doesn't recognize it anymore. So the parent cannot show scrollbars because it doesn't know the size of the inner element `.content`

Comment: This might help. [css overflow: scroll. start from the bottom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34180427/css-overflow-scroll-start-from-the-bottom)

Comment: I want the content to be displayed in the parent, so I set the `position:absolute`, here is a example that can scroll.My question is "why the content can't scroll after add `bottom: 0`(add `top: 10%`don't affect the scroll), and is there a solution to this"
[exapmle can scroll](http://codepen.io/forclan/pen/bZAJEA)

Comment: do you wanna set the scroll position at bottom??

Comment: @forclan : Are you okay with using jquery for this ?

Comment: no, I wanna the content to fill the parent from the top(like set `justify-content: flex-end`)

Comment: @Sree I hope this could be solved in pure CSS

Comment: @forclan : yes you can do that . just to display from bottom and then scroll to top you can use jquery and if you want i can share the code